# maximal acceleration of UIAccelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

i want to track how fast my iPhone is moved.

i checked the AceelerometerGraph Example App, where the maximum Amount was about 2.0 (in this app)

i want to know how exactly i can track the speed of my moving iphone. in this example app the maximum amount is reached very fast. Is there a way to get better results ?

Sry for my bad english :( Comment me if you dont know exactly what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your question is. The subject doesn't really fit the rest of your "question". It is impossible to detect *speed* with an accelerometer. You can only measure *acceleration*. I heard the maximum acceleration that can be detected with the iPhone's accelerometer is approximately 2.5g, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes thanks. so 2.5 kg isnt very much i think. i want to do something like "try to move your iphone as fast as you can in one direction".

Comment: 2.5 G not 2.5 kg. G as in 2.5 times the force of gravity. There is no speed component, just acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's about 2.5G...  Unfortunate, I really wanted to build the iphone version of E39. Oh well.